# Need explanation about breaking from a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, break

I implemented a nested while loop. Here's the source code for the problem:

[While/Break working as expected](https://repl.it/@varun_verma/28-Center-justified-text)

```
 while length < k and i < len(words):
  # Do something
  if len(word) + length < k:
    # Check condition
  else:
    break
 output.append(formatLine(line, length, k))
```

I am trying to build a list of words based on a condition (length of words including space should be less than width k). Once the boundary is reached, I need to break from the inner while loop which I am doing.

BUT - if I add my formatted line to the output list just before the break, I don't get the expected results. If I break the inner while loop and then append the line to the output after coming out from the while loop, I am getting the expected output as in my solution.

So my question is - why is Python behaving in this manner. The variable "line" which is initialized outside of the inner while loop should have the same value just before the break; or if I break the inner while loop and access the value right after that. But that is not happening.

[While/Break not working as you would think](https://repl.it/repls/AllMammothGuiltware)

```
 while length < k and i < len(words):
  # Do something
  if len(word) + length < k:
    # Check condition
  else:
    output.append(formatLine(line, length, k))
    break
```

Comment: So I'm not the only one who mistypes "pythong" all the time :)

Comment: the two code are not equivalent. The lack of a [mcve] here makes it tough to answer, but just ask yourself, are you *sure* the code is always reaching a break? (Because, what happens when the code doesn't reach a break?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference occurs if the `while` condition fails before the `if` condition does.

The first version always executes `output.append()` when the loop ends, whether it's because the condition failed or because of `break`.

The second one only executes it if the loop ends because the `if` condition failed and you break out early.

Comment: Awesome, not sure how I missed that. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop seemingly builds  `line` up to a prescribed `length` from a list of `words`.
Where the line is longer the prescribed `length`, it is `broken`, and a next line continues to be formed with the rest of the words.

This is why appending to `output` list after breaking from the inner loop provides the correct result.

When you append to `output` list before breaking the inner loop, the list may miss some lines because only `line` is longer than the prescribed length and thus broken are added to it.